# How to get the actuall cell text of a jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqgrid placed on a web page that shows data from a database. One of the column is "status". The database query set the cell value as the status id, but in the grid is shown the actual status description. This is right.

Now, I need to retrieve the actual cell text by mean of jquery.

I tried with:

```
var selRowId = $("#contratos").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
var estActualDesc = $("#contratos").jqGrid ('getCell', selRowId, 'estId');
```

But I always get the status id, not the cell text.

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks
Jaime

EDIT:

```
$("#contratos").jqGrid({
    url: "{{ path('_lista_contratos') }}",
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: "GET",
    colNames: ["N° de WF",
        "Fecha Ingreso",
        "Fecha Despacho",
        "Fecha Cierre",
        "Fecha Término",
        "Fecha Aviso",
        "Nombre Fantasía",
        "RUT Contraparte",
        "Nombre Contraparte",
        "Nombre Dado por Contraparte",
        "Gerencia Corporativa",
        "Agencia o Unidad Operativa",
        "Abogado",
        "Estado",
        "Materia",
        "Tipo",
        "Complejidad",
        "N° Memo",
        "Monto UF (anual 3 decimales)",
        "Duración",
        "Cláusula de Salida",
        "Link",
        "Borrador",
        "Observaciones",
        "Fecha de Estado"],
    colModel: [
        {name: "cntWorkflow", width: 90, editable: true, editoptions: {maxlength: 11, size: 17}, editrules: {required: true, custom: true, custom_func: check_wf}, formoptions: {elmsuffix: '<span class="required">*</span>'}},
        {name: "cntFechaIngreso", width: 100, editable: true, editrules: {date: true, required: true}, formoptions: {elmsuffix: '<span class="required">*</span>'}, formatoptions: {srcformat: 'SortableDateTime', newformat: 'd-m-Y'}, editoptions: {size: 17, dataInit: function(el) {
                    $(el).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
                    $(el).mask("?99-99-9999");
                }}, searchoptions: {dataInit: function(el) {
                    $(el).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
                    $(el).mask("?99-99-9999");
                }}},
        {name: "cntFechaDespacho", width: 110, editable: true, editrules: {date: true, required: false}, formatoptions: {srcformat: 'SortableDateTime', newformat: 'd-m-Y'}, editoptions: {size: 17, dataInit: function(el) {
                    $(el).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
                    $(el).mask("?99-99-9999");
                }}, searchoptions: {dataInit: function(el) {
                    $(el).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
                    $(el).mask("?99-99-9999");
                }}},
        {name: "cntFechaCierre", width: 100, editable: true, editrules: {date: true, required: false}, formatoptions: {srcformat: 'SortableDateTime', newformat: 'd-m-Y'}, editoptions: {size: 17, dataInit: function(el) {
                    $(el).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
                    $(el).mask("?99-99-9999");
                }}, searchoptions: {dataInit: function(el) {
                    $(el).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
                    $(el).mask("?99-99-9999");
                }}},
        {name: "cntFechaTermino", width: 100, editable: true, hidden: true, editrules: {date: true, required: false, edithidden: true}, formatoptions: {srcformat: 'SortableDateTime', newformat: 'd-m-Y'}, editoptions: {size: 17, dataInit: function(el) {
                    $(el).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
                    $(el).mask("?99-99-9999");
                }}, searchoptions: {dataInit: function(el) {
                    $(el).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
                    $(el).mask("?99-99-9999");
                }}},
        {name: "cntFechaAviso", width: 100, editable: true, hidden: true, editrules: {date: true, required: false, edithidden: true}, formatoptions: {srcformat: 'SortableDateTime', newformat: 'd-m-Y'}, editoptions: {size: 17, dataInit: function(el) {
                    $(el).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
                    $(el).mask("?99-99-9999");
                }}, searchoptions: {dataInit: function(el) {
                    $(el).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
                    $(el).mask("?99-99-9999");
                }}},
        {name: "cntNombreFantasia", width: 150, editable: true, editoptions: {maxlength: 80, size: 50}},
        {name: "cntRutContraparte", width: 110, editable: true, editoptions: {maxlength: 20, size: 17, dataInit: function(el) {
                    $.mask.definitions['~'] = '[0-9kK]';
                    $(el).mask("?99.999.999-~");
                }}, editrules: {required: true, custom: true, custom_func: is_rut}, formoptions: {elmsuffix: '<span class="required">*</span>'}, searchoptions: {dataInit: function(el) {
                    $.mask.definitions['~'] = '[0-9kK]';
                    $(el).mask("?99.999.999-~");
                }}},
        {name: "cntNombreContraparte", width: 150, hidden: true, editable: true, editoptions: {maxlength: 80, size: 50}, editrules: {required: false, edithidden: true}},
        {name: "cntNombreDadoContraparte", width: 150, hidden: true, editable: true, editoptions: {maxlength: 80, size: 50}, editrules: {required: false, edithidden: true}},
        {name: "gerencia", width: 200, editable: true, edittype: "select", formatter: 'select', editoptions: {style: 'width: 310px', value: '{{ gerencias }}',
                dataEvents: [
                    {type: 'change',
                        fn: function(e) {
                            populate_agencias(this.value, 0);
                        }
                    }
                ]}, stype: 'select', searchoptions: {sopt: ['eq'], value: '{{ gerencias }}'}},
        {name: "agcId", width: 200, editable: true, edittype: "select", formatter: 'select', editrules: {required: true}, formoptions: {elmsuffix: '<span class="required">*</span>'}, editoptions: {style: 'width: 310px', value: '{{ agencias }}'}, stype: 'select', searchoptions: {sopt: ['eq'], value: '{{ agencias }}'}},
        {name: "abgRut", width: 150, editable: true, edittype: "select", formatter: 'select', editrules: {required: true}, formoptions: {elmsuffix: '<span class="required">*</span>'}, editoptions: {style: 'width: 310px', value: '{{ abogados }}'}, stype: 'select', searchoptions: {sopt: ['eq'], value: '{{ abogados }}'}},
        {name: "estId", width: 200, editable: true, edittype: "select", formatter: 'select', editoptions: {style: 'width: 310px', value: '{{ estados }}'}, editrules: {required: true}, formoptions: {elmsuffix: '<span class="required">*</span>'}, stype: 'select', searchoptions: {sopt: ['eq'], value: '{{ estados }}'}},
        {name: "dmnMateriaId", width: 200, editable: true, hidden: true, edittype: "select", formatter: 'select', editoptions: {style: 'width: 310px', value: '{{ materias }}'}, stype: 'select', searchoptions: {sopt: ['eq'], value: '{{ materias }}'}, editrules: {required: false, edithidden: true}},
        {name: "tipo", width: 200, editable: true, hidden: true, edittype: "select", formatter: 'select', editoptions: {style: 'width: 310px', value: '{{ tipos }}'}, stype: 'select', searchoptions: {sopt: ['eq'], value: '{{ tipos }}'}, editrules: {required: false, edithidden: true}},
        {name: "dmnComplejidadId", width: 200, editable: true, hidden: true, edittype: "select", formatter: 'select', editoptions: {style: 'width: 310px', value: '{{ complejidades }}'}, stype: 'select', searchoptions: {sopt: ['eq'], value: '{{ complejidades }}'}, editrules: {required: false, edithidden: true}},
        {name: "cntMemo", width: 90, editable: true, hidden: true, editoptions: {maxlength: 11, size: 17, dataInit: function(el) {
                    $(el).spinner({min: 0});
                }}, editrules: {required: false, edithidden: true}},
        {name: "cntMonto", width: 90, editable: true, hidden: true, editoptions: {maxlength: 11, size: 17, dataInit: function(el) {
                    $(el).spinner({min: 0});
                }}, editrules: {required: false, edithidden: true}},
        {name: "cntDuracion", width: 200, editable: true, hidden: true, edittype: "select", formatter: 'select', editoptions: {style: 'width: 310px', value: '{{ duraciones }}'}, stype: 'select', searchoptions: {sopt: ['eq'], value: '{{ duraciones }}'}, editrules: {required: false, edithidden: true}},
        {name: "cntEsSalida", editable: true, hidden: true, edittype: "checkbo  x", formatter: 'checkbox', editrules: {required: false, edithidden: true}},
        {name: "cntLink", width: 150, hidden: true, editable: true, editoptions: {maxlength: 80, size: 50}, editrules: {required: false, edithidden: true}},
        {name: "cntEsBorrador", editable: true, hidden: true, edittype: "checkbox", formatter: 'checkbox', editrules: {required: false, edithidden: true}},
        {name: "cntObservacion", width: 150, hidden: true, editable: true, editoptions: {maxlength: 80, size: 50}, editrules: {required: false, edithidden: true}},
        {name: 'cntFechaEstado', hidden: true, editable: true, edittype: 'custom', editoptions: {custom_element: statusDateElement, custom_value: statusDateValue}, editrules: {edithidden: false}, formatoptions: {srcformat: 'SortableDateTime', newformat: 'd-m-Y H:i:s'}}
    ],
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: true,
        id: "cntWorkflow"
    },
    pager: "#paginacion",
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    sortname: "cntWorkflow",
    sortorder: "asc",
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    autoencode: true,
    multiselect: false,
    shrinkToFit: false,
    caption: "Listado de Contratos",
    rownumbers: true,
    rownumWidth: 40,
    autowidth: true,
    height: 'auto',
    editurl: "{{ path('_almacena_contrato') }}",
});

$("#contratos").jqGrid('navGrid', '#paginacion',
        {edit: true, add: true, del: false, search: false},
{closeAfterEdit: true, width: 550, beforeShowForm: function(formid) {
        var selRowId = $("#contratos").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
        populate_agencias($("#contratos").jqGrid('getCell', selRowId, 'gerencia'), $("#contratos").jqGrid('getCell', selRowId, 'agcId'));
        var estActualId = $("#contratos").jqGrid('getCell', selRowId, 'estId');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '{{ path('_obtiene_estados_permitidos') }}',
            data: 'estado=' + estActualId,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(estados) {
                $('#estId').empty();
                var optgroup = $('#estId').append(new Option('-- Estado Actual --', estActualId));
                if (estados.length > 0)
                {
                    $('<optGroup/>').attr('label', 'Estados Siguientes').appendTo('#estId');
                    $.each(estados, function() {
                        optgroup.append(new Option(this.descripcion, this.id));
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }, afterShowForm: function(form) {
        $('#cntWorkflow').attr('readonly', true);
        $('#agcId').empty();
        $('#agcId').append(new Option('Seleccione primero la Gerencia', ''));
        form.css("height", "400px");
        form.closest('div.ui-jqdialog').center();
        form.append('<input type="hidden" id="oldEstId" value="' + $('#estId').val() + '" />');
    },
    onclickSubmit: function(params, posdata) {
        return {oldEstId: $('#oldEstId').val()};
    },
    editData: {
        '_csrf_token': '{{ csrf_token }}'
    }
},
{closeAfterAdd: true, recreateForm: true, width: 550, beforeShowForm: function(formid) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '{{ path('_obtiene_estados_permitidos') }}',
            data: 'estado=0',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(estados) {
                $('#estId').empty();
                $('#estId').append(new Option('', ''));
                $.each(estados, function() {
                    $('#estId').append(new Option(this.descripcion, this.id));
                });
            }
        })
    }, afterShowForm: function(form) {
        $('#agcId').empty();
        $('#agcId').append(new Option('Seleccione primero la Gerencia', ''));
        form.css("height", "400px");
        form.closest('div.ui-jqdialog').center();
    },
    editData: {
        '_csrf_token': '{{ csrf_token }}'
    }
},
{},
        {multipleSearch: false, multipleGroup: false})
        .navSeparatorAdd("#paginacion", {sepclass: "ui-separator", sepcontent: ''})
        .navButtonAdd("#paginacion",
        {caption: "",
            buttonicon: "ui-icon-note",
            onClickButton: function() {
                if ($('#contratos').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow') == null)
                    $.jgrid.info_dialog($.jgrid.errors.errcap, 'Seleccione un contrato', $.jgrid.edit.bClose);
                else
                    location.href = '{{ path('_bitacora') }}/' + $('#contratos').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
            },
            position: "last", title: "Ver bitácora del contrato seleccionado", cursor: "pointer"
        });
$("#contratos").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {searchOperators: false});

$.jgrid.edit.addCaption = "Agregar Contrato";
$.jgrid.edit.editCaption = "Modificar Contrato";
$.jgrid.edit.saveData = "¡El contrato fue modificado! ¿Almacena los cambios?";

$.jgrid.formatter.date.newformat = 'd-m-Y H:i';
```

Comment: Could be attached to the grid source code?

Comment: I have attached the grid code.

Comment: Thank you, I checked. It's works for me: I not get back the ID, but the text of the selected item. So, Let's go further. Can you show me the definition of '{{ estados }}'?

Comment: And what is the value of estActualDesc?